# Selenium Webdriver in C# - Issue with TimeSpan command

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium Webdriver in Visual Studio 2013. I installed webdriver through nuget and added the C# references from SeleniumHQ.org
This is my first attempt at running a test with Webdriver and I have no knowledge of or experience in programming.
I am getting an error on the TimeSpan command and was wondering if anyone could help.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

The TimeSpan command in this line throws an error that says "The name 'TimeSpan' does not exist in the current context.
Thoughts?

Comment: rightclick TimeSpan -> resolve -> add using directive

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Now upon running the test Visual Studio says "A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.     Im lost.

Comment: Well it's correct - you've built it as a library. Show us the code you are using.

Comment: using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
class GoogleSuggest
{static void Main(string[] args)
{IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")); query.SendKeys("Cheese");                         query.Submit();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10));
wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); });

      
System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
driver.Quit();

Comment: Sorry about the format. its a c# script from the Selenium site. i am trying to understand how to set my test environment up in Visual Studio 2013 and execute tests there. Is there something else I need? i really appreciate they help

Comment: Do I need to install Nunit to run the tests?